# How to automatically assign port for make Bind() success

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

My program connects different network simultaneously and bind fails sometime if trying to connect using same port number.

Is there any way to check the port number free before assigning

```
     sockopt = 1;
rc = setsockopt(listensock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sockopt, sizeof(sockopt));
sinlen=sizeof(sin);
if (-1 == bind(listensock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sinlen)) {
    perror("bind");
    return 0;
}
if (-1 == listen(listensock, 2)) {
    perror("listen");
    return 0;
}
```

This function fails if I assign same previously assigned port for new connection.

Comment: There is no need to explicitely bind your sockets prior to `connect()`. They will be automatically bound to an interface.

Comment: Connect is also failing because of same port no

Comment: Are you sure of that? For any socket you want to use a `connect()` call with, remove the bind calls. Have you checked the error codes if they really relate to an "address already in use" error?

Comment: Yes bind failed because of same port number, when I manually gave different port number its working fine

Comment: You have to read more carefully. *You do not need any bind calls, remove them.* connect() will automatically bind to a available address when successful.

Comment: OK I will remove bind any try

Comment: After commenting bind connect is failing

Comment: I would suggest to read again on some tutorials. Calling `listen()` on a socket you want to actively connect makes no sense. You use listen when you want to accept connections.

Comment: There is **usually** no reason to call `bind()` before `connect()`, but you **can** if a specific port is needed by a firewall or protocol requirement.  Otherwise, just let `connect()` pick an available port for you. You do need `bind()` before `listen()`, though, and you can't have multiple sockets on the same machine listening on the same port on the same network interface, only on different interfaces.

Comment: You're not checking if setsockopt() succeeded. There your problems may have started.

Besides, I lack some context: how the socket was initialized, what types you're using for sockopt. There may be multiple reasons why this fails.